# How to split one column to more by header of new data

Tags: python

I have csv file like this

[file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co0yH.png)

And want to split this column to more by line where is Ubat. Because another Ubat is another measurements and I want each measurement in one column because I want calculate mean of this numbers but for each measurement separately.

I want do it in python but my tries not works

Thanks

Comment: hello missto3, welcome to stackover flow! Here some advices in order to help you more easily: (1) add a fully running code, (2) in your example: make the data ready, so it can be copied, (3) sketch how your result should look like. With that, you will find some people  having good ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a dataframe `df` like this

```py
>>> df
    Ubat
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4   Ubat
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      9
10  Ubat
11    10
12    11
13    12
```

Add a boolean column `groups`:

```py
>>> df['groups'] = df.Ubat.eq('Ubat')
>>> df
    Ubat  groups
0      1   False
1      2   False
2      3   False
3      4   False
4   Ubat    True
5      5   False
6      6   False
7      7   False
8      8   False
9      9   False
10  Ubat    True
11    10   False
12    11   False
13    12   False
```

Turn it into an accumulating counter with `.cumsum()`:

```py
>>> df['groups'] = df['groups'].cumsum()
>>> df
    Ubat  groups
0      1       0
1      2       0
2      3       0
3      4       0
4   Ubat       1
5      5       1
6      6       1
7      7       1
8      8       1
9      9       1
10  Ubat       2
11    10       2
12    11       2
13    12       2
```

Now you can group them via `df.groupby('groups')`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works, but now if i use

```
df['groups'] = df.Ubat.eq('Ubat')
df['groups'] = df['groups'].cumsum()
dfgroup = df.groupby('groups').mean()

g=df.groupby('groups')
g=df.replace('Ubat',)
meanvbat=g.groupby('groups').Ubat.mean()
print (meanvbat)
```

I got the error TypeError: Could not convert to numeric and very long number i dont know why because if i use min or max it works but not for mean this vaules.